# How to make a tail-recursive method which calls itself in a flatMap?

Tags: scala, recursion

I want to make the following recursive method tail-recursive, but I am not sure if this is even possible, since the method is calling itself inside a `flatMap`.

```
@tailrec
def loop(nodes: List[Node], myNodes: List[MyNode]): List[MyNode] = nodes match {
  case Nil => myNodes
  case _ =>
    nodes.flatMap { n =>
      val myNode = MyNode(data = n.data)
      loop(n.getChildNodes().toList, myNode :: myNodes)
    }
}

loop(nodes, List())
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
could not optimize @tailrec annotated method loop: it contains a recursive call not in tail position
[error]           case _ =>
[error]                  ^
[error] one error found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @SteffenSchmitz said, you cannot make the recursive call inside a `flatMap`. Indeed, in the case where the list has at least two `Node`s, your method will have at least two calls to itself, so it cannot be tailrec. However, you can do the same that your logic is doing here with tail-recursion.

What your code is doing, is copying data in `Node`s in `nodes` which seems to be sone kind of tree structure into a `List[MyNode]`.

In the end, you get the list of all the ancestors for each of the leaves of the original tree.

For instance, if your tree is

```
  A
 / \
B   C
   / \
  D   E
```

You'll get `List(B, A, D, C, A, E, C, A)` (here, I'm assuming `data` is a `Char`, for simplicity). The first `B, A` are the ancestors for `B`, the next `D, C, A` are the ancestors for `D`, and the last ones for `E`.

You can do the same with the following tailrec:

```
@tailrec
def tailrecLoop(nodesWithAncestors: List[(Node, List[MyNode])], acc: List[MyNode]): List[MyNode] = {
  nodesWithAncestors.headOption match {
    case None => acc
    case Some((node, ancestors)) if node.getChildNodes().toList.isEmpty =>
      loop(nodes.tail, acc ::: myNode :: ancestors)
    case Some((node, ancestors)) =>
      val myNode = MyNode(data = node.data)
      val childrenWithAncestors = 
        node.getChildNodes().toList.map(_ -> (myNode :: ancestors))
      loop(childrenWithAncestors ++ nodes.tail, acc)
  }
}

def loop(nodes: List[Node]) = tailrecLoop(nodes.map(_ -> Nil), Nil)
```

The key here is to put the non-treated nodes (`nodesWithAncestors`) in a queue, to be handled at some later time by sub-calls.

Comment: @Dima I agree that this is probably not the intent of the code, but it is what it does.

Comment: It's not ... That's what I meant.

Comment: My bad. The ancestor list should actually also include the leaf. I'll correct this right now.

Comment: No, there are no "ancestor lists". This is just a regular preorder traversal.

Comment: Have you tried actually running the code? This is what it does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145382/discussion-between-cyrille-corpet-and-dima).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to make a call inside a flatmap tail-recursive. The last call in your function has to be loop().